# International routing in Next js based on region

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, url-routing, i18next

I am using next.js version 12.2.5. I want to create internationalized region-based sub-path routing in my web app as https://www.apple.com/ do. Let's say the user from Australia lands on my web app, so my route should be like '${mydomain}/au' and the rest of the pages in my web application should be like for eg '${mydomain}/au/faq', '${mydomain}/au/blog' etc. Similarly, if the user from another country let's say India lands on my web application the routing should work like: '${mydomain}/in' and the rest of the pages in my web application should be like for eg '${mydomain}/in/blog', '${mydomain}/in/faq', '${mydomain}/in/about' etc.

I am using i18n sub-path routing strategies of next js. Which allows me to create sub-path routes based on locales. So if a user from Australia comes to my website. My route is automatically changed to '${mydomain}/en-Au' based on the locale configured in my browser.

I only want to show the region in the route i.e '${mydomain}/au' not the complete locale. Can anyone help me to achieve my end goal using the same strategy I am following? Please suggest me a better way of doing this, If I am following the wrong approach.

Your help would be really appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can use the useRouter hook from Next.js to get the locale and region parameters of the current route